# Paypal payment page odd behavior

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated Express Checkout with my application it works fine but sometimes paypal payment pages behaves very oddly. When user is directed to payment page, the page it shows is not same all the time. sometimes it shows saying "Login or Checkout as a Guest" and sometimes user see a page saying "Login as paypal or Create an account"

I have attached the image url Please see the following links.

First Layout

http://oi60.tinypic.com/149rpcn.jpg

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2r43ms2.jpg

Second Layout

http://oi58.tinypic.com/vxcl04.jpg

http://oi62.tinypic.com/v3j3hc.jpg

First layout makes sense. but second layout creating confusion when it says "create an account"? is that means creating paypal account or what? when i click on the option it simply shows me credit card details to enter. i dont know if that is related to the payment or asking to create new paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has been split testing the old EC pages with the new ones that you're seeing sometimes.  In order to work with both sets of pages nicely, you'll need to make sure to add an additional parameter into your SetExpressCheckout request.

It looks like you're already using the following (and if you're not, you need to add them)

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing

You need to also include the following to work well with the new pages.

- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

Comment: i am already adding these three parameters to my request. but getting the same behavior.

Comment: You're sure you're using that 3rd one?  I was getting what you're getting until I added that new parameter, which was just introduced not too long ago.

Comment: It should, yeah.  You'll just need to confirm by looking at the raw API request that gets generated.

Comment: I am passing all paramters but problem is still there. i am from Pakistan, it works good when i access the site from my country. but when this site is accessed in uk. it shows them to checkout as guest screen first. ?

Comment: Try including a LOCALECODE parameter in your SEC request with a value that you know works.